# NSString new line doesn't work in mail?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, mfmailcomposer

I have two UITextViews that I want to be displayed when the user sends mail. The problem is that I want the text from the second textview to be displayed in a new line in the mail.

I've tried with NSLog and it works just fine there, is there a problem with the mail API or why is not working properly?

My code looks like this:

```
NSString *desc = descriptionTextView.text;
NSString *ingredients = ingredientsTextView.text;
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", desc, ingredients];
NSLog(@"%@\n\n%@", desc, ingredients);

-(void)displayComposerSheet
```

{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

```
[picker setSubject:titleLabel.text];
NSString *desc = descriptionTextView.text;
NSString *ingredients = ingredientsTextView.text;
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@", desc, ingredients];
NSLog(@"%@\n\n%@", desc, ingredients);
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES];


[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
```

}

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
titleLabel.text = [recipeData valueForKey:@"title"];
descriptionTextView.text = [recipeData valueForKey:@"description"];
ingredientsTextView.text = [recipeData valueForKey:@"ingredients"];
[super viewDidLoad];
```

}

Comment: Can you show us where you're setting this text in the MFMailComposer?

Comment: I think you should add that code to the question and format it appropriately.  I can't read it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In mail composing just use the html tags then it works fine.
Use a html `<br />` tag for a new line.

```
NSString *desc = descriptionTextView.text;
NSString *ingredients = ingredientsTextView.text;
NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ <br/> <br/> %@", desc, ingredients];
// [email setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:YES]; 
NSLog(@"%@\n\n%@", desc, ingredients);
```